# Find out committed transactions before specific datetime

Tags: sql-server, database-backups, database-restore

We have got a legacy system. We are migrating to new platform. We took backup of production database on January 6, 2021 and restored in UAT environment.

Below query, we ran to get the backup datetime of the production database from UAT environment. [Reference Article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1860/identify-when-a-sql-server-database-was-restored-the-source-and-backup-date/)

```sql
SELECT 
    [rs].[destination_database_name], 
    [rs].[restore_date], 
    [bs].[backup_start_date], 
    [bs].[backup_finish_date], 
    [bs].[database_name] AS [source_database_name], 
    [bmf].[physical_device_name] AS [backup_file_used_for_restore]
FROM 
    msdb..restorehistory rs
INNER JOIN 
    msdb..backupset bs ON [rs].[backup_set_id] = [bs].[backup_set_id]
INNER JOIN 
    msdb..backupmediafamily bmf ON [bs].[media_set_id] = [bmf].[media_set_id] 
ORDER BY 
    [rs].[restore_date] DESC
```

| destination_database_name | restore_date | backup_start_date | backup_finish_date | source_database_name | backup_file_used_for_restore |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| our_DB | 2021-01-06 06:02:21.620 | 2021-01-06 00:12:55.000 | 2021-01-06 00:39:06.000 | our_DB | E:\our_DB.bak |

In production database, we keep processing inbound flat files. We process files and commit them, as and when they come.

We want to pull the list of delta flat files, which came after we took the backup and not already processed.

So, should we consider `backup_finish_datetime` (`2021-01-06 00:39:06.000`) or `backup_start_date` (`2021-01-06 00:12:55.000`) for picking up delta files from production ?

Comment: I think `backup_start_date` as rowversioning would start from there, might be wrong

Comment: The date and time of a RESTORE (not backup) has no direct association the date and time the associated backup was created. Without getting too deep, the date and time of a backup will be difficult to use to determine when any particular "delta flat file" was processed (guessing - you don't explain what this means) in your production system. I think you make some significant and unsafe assumptions.

Comment: delta flat file contains records for inserting to the production system. you are right, we don't know which delta flat file would have been processed or not, considering some delta flat files are bigger.

Comment: @SMor, you are right. please add your answer. I will accept it. We decided it is risky to go with this kind of delta files approach. We decided that it is fine for little overlap of delta files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the complexities involved in figuring out the committed transactions and ongoing transactions at the backup finish time, we decided, not to go with the backup finish time as delta time.

We decided to go for all incremental delta files, since start of the day (2021-01-06 00:00:00.000) & we understand that there will be some duplicate entries and we have to handle it accordingly in the new system.

As we don't have audit columns, we decided to take this option. It highlights the important of audit columns.